# Visual studio 2010, PortAudio DLL compile and linking issues, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include-path, portaudio

Hi stack overflow users.

**Error description:**

For a mini project I have decided to use the portaudio library (I use Windows 7 64-bit and C++): http://portaudio.com/

Before even using the library I had to build a .DLL file in another Visual Studio Project and then link the output to my own visual studio 2010 project (32-bit). I tried to use this simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <portaudio.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;   cout << "Welcome to C++ Programming" << endl; }
```

I get this error message:
*fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory*

I personally don't think it is the creation of the .DLL that is the issue but more a linking issue.

**My attempt:**

First of all I have attempted to follow this guide: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html

By following this guide, I got a compiled .DLL and .Lib files inside the release folder(Image 1):

Afterwards I try to link my visual studio 2010 with portaudio_x86.lib and include the directory where it is located (The output folder of the .DLL creation)(Image 2 and 3)

I myself have very poor experience with using external libraries and even less experience when compiling them yourself. I have only a little experience with previous programming, so I am pretty sure it is just me missing something vital.

[image: The folder filled with the .DLL and .Lib files][image: Telling the linker which library to include]
[image: Telling the project what directory to include (In this case, the folder where the .DLL and .Lib is]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler fails to find the `portaudio.h` header file. As per the last screenshot, in *Additional Include Directories*, you need to point to the directory where the `<portaudio.h>` file is, not where the binaries (`.lib`, `.dll`) are. The path to the `.lib` file needs to either be specified explicitly (as in the next to the last screenshot, not just `portaudio.lib` but the full path) or set in the *VC++ Directories* property page, which is also the preferred place to set your include directories.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it resolved with your help.
Changed all the directories in the VC++ towards the .DLL project as well as pointing at portaudio.h