# portaudio in visual studio 2015, missing .dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, portaudio

I'm trying to compile a c++ source file in visual studio 2015 which uses the port audio API, after downloading and compiling port audio I need to link the dll/lib files and any header files I need for the program. I managed to include the .lib and .h files easily but I am having trouble with the **portaudio x86.dll** file not being found, I don't know what problem is causing this or what further linking is required to include **portaudio_x86.dll**

Error message, .dll not found? 
[image]

successfully included the.lib file, dll is in the same directory!! 
[image]

linked the .lib file in additional directories, should I do the same with the .dll file here? 
[image]

similar question at this link, helped my a little bit but didn't solve my problem :[Visual studio 2010, PortAudio DLL compile and linking issues, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669187/visual-studio-2010-portaudio-dll-compile-and-linking-issues-c/10669227)

Comment: I found a solution at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518082/dll-dependency-not-found-when-debugging-with-visual-studio-11-rc